# php simplexml_load_file can't get right value

Tags: php

I want to get some value from http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/ERS032727&display=xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ROOT request="ERS032727&amp;display=xml">
 <SAMPLE alias="sample_Ae372-1" center_name="Beijing Genome Institute" accession="ERS032727">
 <IDENTIFIERS>
      <PRIMARY_ID>ERS032727</PRIMARY_ID>
      <EXTERNAL_ID namespace="BioSample">SAMEA762107</EXTERNAL_ID>
      <SUBMITTER_ID namespace="BGI">sample_Ae372-1</SUBMITTER_ID>
 </IDENTIFIERS>
 <TITLE>Acromyrmex echinatior</TITLE>
 <SAMPLE_NAME>
      <TAXON_ID>103372</TAXON_ID>
      <SCIENTIFIC_NAME>Acromyrmex echinatior</SCIENTIFIC_NAME>
      <COMMON_NAME>Panamanian leafcutter ant</COMMON_NAME>
 </SAMPLE_NAME>
 <DESCRIPTION>Genome DNA sample for 500bp and 800bp insert size library</DESCRIPTION>
 <SAMPLE_LINKS>
      <SAMPLE_LINK>
           <XREF_LINK>
                <DB>ENA-STUDY</DB>
                <ID>ERP000666</ID>
           </XREF_LINK>
      </SAMPLE_LINK>
      <SAMPLE_LINK>
           <XREF_LINK>
                <DB>ENA-EXPERIMENT</DB>
                <ID>ERX012712-ERX012713</ID>
           </XREF_LINK>
      </SAMPLE_LINK>
      <SAMPLE_LINK>
           <XREF_LINK>
                <DB>ENA-RUN</DB>
                <ID>ERR034186-ERR034187</ID>
           </XREF_LINK>
      </SAMPLE_LINK>
      <SAMPLE_LINK>
           <XREF_LINK>
                <DB>ENA-SUBMISSION</DB>
                <ID>ERA030423</ID>
           </XREF_LINK>
      </SAMPLE_LINK>
      <SAMPLE_LINK>
           <XREF_LINK>
                <DB>ENA-FASTQ-FILES</DB>
                <ID>http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/reports/sra/fastq_files/ERS032727</ID>
           </XREF_LINK>
      </SAMPLE_LINK>
      <SAMPLE_LINK>
           <XREF_LINK>
                <DB>ENA-SUBMITTED-FILES</DB>
                <ID>http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/reports/sra/submitted_files/ERS032727</ID>
           </XREF_LINK>
      </SAMPLE_LINK>
 </SAMPLE_LINKS>
 <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Time of sample collection</TAG>
           <VALUE>2008</VALUE>
           <UNITS>Year</UNITS>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Habitat</TAG>
           <VALUE>Gamboa, Panama</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Sample extracted from</TAG>
           <VALUE>1 male</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Sample type</TAG>
           <VALUE>DNA</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>ENA-SPOT-COUNT</TAG>
           <VALUE>119159746</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>ENA-BASE-COUNT</TAG>
           <VALUE>23831949200</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
 </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>
```

I use $file= simplexml_load_file($path), but i just want to get this parts

```
<SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Time of sample collection</TAG>
           <VALUE>2008</VALUE>
           <UNITS>Year</UNITS>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Habitat</TAG>
           <VALUE>Gamboa, Panama</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Sample extracted from</TAG>
           <VALUE>1 male</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>Sample type</TAG>
           <VALUE>DNA</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>ENA-SPOT-COUNT</TAG>
           <VALUE>119159746</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
      <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
           <TAG>ENA-BASE-COUNT</TAG>
           <VALUE>23831949200</VALUE>
      </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
 </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>
```

i set $file->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES, but can't work.
How can i get each sample attribute in the sample attributes
like

```
Time of sample collection= 2008 Year
Habitat= Gamboa, Panama
Sample extracted from= 1 male
....
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `simplexml_load_string` and a `foreach` to loop through.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/ERS032727&display=xml'));
foreach ($xml->SAMPLE->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE as $child)
{
    echo $child->TAG." = ".$child->VALUE;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Time of sample collection = 2008
Habitat = Gamboa, Panama
Sample extracted from = 1 male
Sample type = DNA
ENA-SPOT-COUNT = 119159746
ENA-BASE-COUNT = 23831949200
```

Comment: Ahem... `$xml->SAMPLE->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE`

Comment: @Phil, I think not :) PS the demo :)

Comment: I think so. The XML document is a remote file and OP has no way of extracting just the `<SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>` node as a string

Comment: @Phil, Right .. Now I generalized it. Passed the `file_get_contents` inside of that.

Comment: You don't need `file_get_contents`. `simplexml_load_file` is perfectly capable of opening a resource over HTTP as OP is already doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the document to the nodes you're interested in. An XPATH expression would be

```
/ROOT/SAMPLE/SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES/SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE
```

With `SimpleXMLElement`, the instance created by `simplexml_load_*` represents the root node so the traversal would be

```
$file->SAMPLE->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE
```

As this represents a collection, you can iterate using conventional means...

```
foreach ($file->SAMPLE->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES->SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE as $attribute) {
    printf('%s= %s%s<br>',
        $attribute->TAG, $attribute->VALUE,
        isset($attribute->UNITS) ? " {$attribute->UNITS}" : '');
}
```